# aws CloudWatch Agent config file log path with

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, agent

I try to do next log path in CloudWatch:
/asg/raw/i-000fdfffdf/httpd

But conf file don't work
I have tried use ${aws:InstanceId}, {aws:InstanceId}

If I do that :

```
                "file_path": "/var/log/httpd/*",
                "log_group_name": "/asg/raw/",
                "log_stream_name": "httpd",
                "timezone": "Local"
              }
```

it is work. But I neet instanceId in path

A part of My conf file:

```
        "logs_collected": {
          "files": {
            "collect_list": [
              {
                "file_path": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log",
                "log_group_name": "/asg/raw/${aws:InstanceId}",
                "log_stream_name": "cloudwatch-agent",
                "timezone": "Local"
              },
              {
                "file_path": "/var/log/crontab_custom.log",
                "log_group_name": "/asg/raw/${aws:InstanceId}",
                "log_stream_name": "crontab",
                "timezone": "Local"
              },
     {
                "file_path": "/var/log/httpd/*",
                "log_group_name": "/asg/raw/${aws:InstanceId}",
                "log_stream_name": "httpd",
                "timezone": "Local"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "log_stream_name": "raw_stream",
        "force_flush_interval" : 15
      }
```

Comment: I used "InstanceId" instead "instance_id"

Answer (score 0):

Seems the line you have used correct only as per [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html), It should work.

```
"log_group_name": "/asg/raw/${aws:InstanceId}"
```

Possible reasons could be

1. Have you restarted the cloudwatch agent after configuration update? if the agent is not restarted agent will not take the latest configuration for pushing to new log group name.
2. By default region for agent will be us-east-1 [US East (N. Virginia)] did you check in that region?

Comment: I decided this problem. Neet to use "instanse_id" instead "InstanceId"